# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE COMMAND several errors

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime-format, load-data-infile

I am trying to load data for Q1 2012 from the below link
https://s3.amazonaws.com/capitalbikeshare-data/index.html

My code is as follows:-

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS bike;
CREATE DATABASE bike;
USE bike;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bike_2012;
CREATE TABLE bike_2012(
bike_duration INT NULL,
bike_start_date TIMESTAMP NULL,
bike_end_date TIMESTAMP NULL,
bike_s_station_no INT(5) NULL,
bike_s_station_name VARCHAR(255) NULL,
bike_e_station_no INT(5) NULL,
bike_e_station_name VARCHAR(255) NULL,
bike_number CHAR(6) NULL,
bike_member_type VARCHAR(25) NULL,
bike_ride_number INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/LAGASA_2018/MSBA/Data_Sources/2012-capitalbikeshare-tripdata/2012Q1-capitalbikeshare-tripdata.csv'
INTO TABLE bike_2012
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '/n'
('bike_duration', @bike_start_date, @bike_end_date, 'bike_s_station_no','bike_s_station_name',
'bike_e_station_no','bike_e_station_name','bike_number','bike_member_type')
SET 'bike_start_date' = STR_TO_DATE(@bike_start_date, '%c/%e/%Y')
SET 'bike_end_date' = STR_TO_DATE(@bike_end_date, '%c/%e/%Y')
IGNORE 1 LINES;

SELECT * FROM bike_2012 LIMIT 10;
```

I am facing the following issues:-

1. Some columns that have integer data also have string data, so those parts are not getting loaded correctly. I tried to add `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` but its not working.
2. Unable to change date to SQL date format
3. Other errors like Row doesn't contain data for all columns and data truncated for date columns are appearing.

I have been struggling to correct this. Please help.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to simply load wrong CSV into DB and fix it.

If you have access to PHP/Python or other language that has a driver to connect to your db engines, load that file into an array, or use something similar to `fgets()` in php to load it line by line and process each row separately, fix/convert data and then push it to db engine (I would suggest even grouping inserts for speed).

You are dealing not only with conversion, but there might be issues with string encoding (you didn't specify any in your `CREATE TABLE` which might cause a problem in itself.